# Stack overflow. Function fails to stop at base case

Tags: scala, recursion, stack-overflow

I have a class called Rational:

```
class Rational(x:Int,y:Int){

def numer=x
def denom=y

def add(r: Rational) =
new Rational(numer* r.denom+ r.numer* denom,
denom* r.denom)

override def toString= numer+ "/"+ denom
def neg = new Rational(-numer, denom)
def -(that: Rational) = add(that.neg)
def < (that:Rational)=numer * that.denom < that.numer * denom
def max(that:Rational)=
if (this < (that)) that else this

def / (r: Rational) = new Rational(numer * r.denom, denom * r.numer)
def numerMIn = new Rational(numer -1, denom)
def denomMIn = new Rational(numer, denom-1)

}
```

I've written this function, which is a subfunction of a bigger one. I'm just debugging it.
Assume b is the Rational 3/4 and we pass the Rational 2/4 into iter.

```
def iter(c:Rational): Rational={

        if (c.denom==0) new Rational(0,0) else if(!(c < b)) denomDec(c) else c add iter(denomDec(c))

    }
```

And here's denomDec:

```
def denomDec(r: Rational) = new Rational(r.numer, r.denom-1)
```

The problem is that the iter function does not stop and runs into Stack Overflow.

Here's what happens inside iter(). It gets 2/4 as argument. Then itake 2/4 + 2/3 + when it reaches 2/2, it calls denomDec to get 2/1 after 2/2 because the latter fails to be smaller than 3/4. Then denomDec gets to 2/0 and here it is supposed to return new Rational(0,0) but it fails to do so which in its turn causes Stack Overflow.

My question is that why doesn't the function stop when recurring when it hits the base case which is `if denomDec(r: Rational) = new Rational(r.numer, r.denom-1)`

For clarification: example iter(2/4) should do this: 2/4 + 2/3 + 0/0. 
2/2 and 2/1 are skipped as they are both greater than 3/4.

Comment: Have tried `iter(2/0)`?  If that *stops*, then your problem is that your recursion isn't getting to that point.

Comment: it does does to that point. I've tested it. What it does is that it keeps calling denomDec so you get 2/0, 2/-1, 2/-2....

Comment: There are so many problems with this code that it's a wonder it works at all. `Rational(0, 0)` should not be allowed to exist, `<` does not work correctly, which breaks almost every other method. Consider: val a = new Rational(1,2) , val b = new Rational(3,-4), a < b returns true, but clearly 1/2 < -3/4 is false.

Comment: Forgot to let you that you are not interested in negative Rationals, so the negative part is irrelevant. When the denominator of the Rational is 0, you have to return 0/0 which is okay to do for this specific problem. I just dont see why this recursion does not stop.

Comment: It seems to work for me: `scala> iter(new Rational(2,4))`
`res0: Rational = 38/12`
Does the 'b' change duing the iterations ?

Comment: But it is not supposed to be 38/12. Instead it needs to do 2/4 + 2/3 which is 14/12....

Answer (score 0):

Rational(0,0) is not zero. When you do math on it you are getting bad results. Consider the case Rational(0,0) < Rational(1,2). It should be true, but your < operator evaluates it like this: 0*2 < 1*0, which is the same as 0 < 0 which is false.

In iter() our second if statement does not work correct when it evaluates Rational(0,0) and the Rational(0,0) gets passed to the denonDec and its denominator goes negative. Once that happens you're sunk.

I would put a guard in the Rational constructor to prevent denoms less than 1. I would use Rational(0,1) as zero. Remember from basic arithmetic that the fraction 0/0 is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your problem is out of the presented scope;
I have tested code and I do not get error:

```
 iter(new Rational(2,4))                         
  //> denomDec | old / new denom 4 / 3
  //| denomDec | old / new denom 3 / 2
  //| iter | c<b
  //| denomDec | old / new denom 2 / 1
  //| add | adding two rationals: 2/3, 2/1
  //| add | it gives: 8/3
  //| add | adding two rationals: 2/4, 8/3
  //| add | it gives: 38/12
  //| res0: test.Rational = 38/12   

 iter(new Rational(2,0))
    //> iter | denom=0
  //| res0: test.Rational = 0/0      

 iter(new Rational(0,4))
 //> denomDec | old / new denom 4 / 3
  //| denomDec | old / new denom 3 / 2
  //| denomDec | old / new denom 2 / 1
  //| denomDec | old / new denom 1 / 0
  //| iter | denom=0
  //| add | adding two rationals: 0/1, 0/0
  //| add | it gives: 0/0
  //| add | adding two rationals: 0/2, 0/0
  //| add | it gives: 0/0
  //| add | adding two rationals: 0/3, 0/0
  //| add | it gives: 0/0
  //| add | adding two rationals: 0/4, 0/0
  //| add | it gives: 0/0
  //| res0: test.Rational = 0/0
```

Comment: The problem is that is doesn't do what its supposed to. It has to do this: 2/4 + 2/3 +0/0 skipping 2/2 and 2/1 because these two are bigger than 3/4. The code is not supposed to go on after hitting 2/0 as @guzial

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is wrong with my code above. 
Instead of `else if(!(c < h)) denomDec(c)` I should do `else if(!(c < h)) iter(denomDec(c))` so that I actually call the `iter()` function again with a smaller argument.
Another mistake of mine was trying to add 0/0 to another `Rational`. The problem is that if you look at my code for add `def add(r: Rational) = new Rational(numer* r.denom+ r.numer* denom,denom* r.denom)` you can see that adding 0/0 to any `Rational` will always return 0/0. Hence, I need to return something other than `new Rational(0,0)` when the base case is reached.